# return ajax response in chunked mode

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I want to make a progress bar for processing some data in server.
I don't want to reload the page or go to another page, so I used an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "/process.php",
    dataType: "script",
    data: "foo=bar",
    success: function(data){

    }
});
```

And this request returns some code like:

```
set_progress(50);
```

over and over in chunked mode.
but ajax wait until request is finished and then return response data!
so that couldn't be useful :(

after that I tested another way.
I used a iframe for a regular http form.

```
<form action="/process.php" method="post" target="iframe" id="formid">
   <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
</form>
<iframe name="iframe"></iframe>
```

and even this method didn't work :((( 
It will run all javascript codes at the end of request not throw request!

I know the regular work to make this work is send user to another page and then send chunked data like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">setProgress(percent);</script>
```

but I prefer to not use this way ;)
there is any way to make this work?

Comment: How about starting your server process A1 and keep polling your server to determine the percentage completion? Use setInterval() method to poll your server for status every n seconds and update the client.

Comment: yes, I was using this method in previous version of my site. but it is not smooth like I want!! :(  . I found a way to make javascript codes run during loading(not after finishing it) in iframe method. but here it is another problem! I can not access window.opener because iframe still is loading when I want to use this! do you know any way to set window.opener property from parent window before submitting form?